# Android create a single Datetime string from separate Time and Date picker widgets

Tags: android, datetime, android-datepicker

I have a layout that contains two EditText field, one for a date and one for a time. When clicked twice, each launches its respective ticker.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/task_due_date"
        android:inputType="datetime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_insert_invitation_black_18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/task_title"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:hint="@string/date_due_hint"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time_due"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/task_due_date"
        android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
        android:hint="@string/time_due_hint"/>
```

In my Activity class there are two methods to launch the Dialog fragments.

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
```

Unfortunately, right now I don't know how to create a single datetime timestamp from the two separate Pickers. My current solution is

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, day);
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_due_date)).setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }

@Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
        String format = "HH:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(hour, minute);
        String date = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_due_date)).getText().toString();
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_due_date)).setText(date + " " + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }
```

The last two line of `onTimeSet` are where i'm stuck. Current way is horrible and it doesn't create a proper timestamp, it currently looks like `7/27/15 13:30` . Ideally I'd like to remove the "time_due" EditText field all together and find a way to populate the `task_due_date` EditText with something that looks like: "July 27, 4:30 PM" and could then be written to my db as a datetime timestamp. What's the best way to combine the output of the two Pickers into a single timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a Calendar variable in your activity/fragment, and when the time/date is set, simply use the .set(int field, int value) function to set year/month/day/hour/minute.

That would give you 1, always updated, instance of Calendar, which you can then format however you want to, like showing it as "July 27, 4:30 PM".